# I asked a question and accepted an answer too quickly

Tags: support

I recently asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1201773/i-want-to-intercept-a-given-program-before-it-runs-and-run-my-own-program-first) that seemed to be quite difficult to answer. I got only one answer, which I approved because it seemed to do exactly what I wanted it to do. When I later started experimenting it turned out that it doesn't work as well as I thought. Now I have a bunch of new questions connected to that answer if it's ever to work. I asked them to the original answerer, but I think I'm having too long discussions in the comments for this site's liking and I can't open a chat because I don't have enough reputation. How should I proceed? I don't want to spam the same question. What should I do in the more general case of there being no answers?

Comment: If there are no answers what would you accept?

Comment: Think about why you didn't get any answers and work from there. Improving the question might help or doing some research and come back with a different question is also an option.

Comment: You can unaccept an answer at any point.  If you don't do that, it's unlikely, you will get any additional answers, that are worth while (just comments submitted as answers sadly).

Comment: What happens if I unaccept an answer, will it go back to the top and become noticed?

random: That part of the question had more to do with whether I should ask it again or something like that.

Comment: @GoodDay - Your question will not appear on the first page, unless you provide an edit, and it should be a substantial edit.  *If you ask the same question (again) it will simply be closed as a duplicate of your original.*  However, the fudmental question, should not be changed.  If the answer you recieve does not answer the question, and that is because your question lacks clarity, then you should provide that clarification.